# Chat module integration in code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, livechat

i'm developing a website in codeigniter. In my site, i need to integrate live-chat like google chat option for my site user. Can you suggest me any chat code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chat uses the [XMPP protocol](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol), you might wanna take a look at [the docs](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html). While not a CI solution, [XMPPHP](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) is a great class to get you up and running with XMPP. It wouldn't be to hard to port it to a CI library.